# Why can't suspensions be prepared on beat 4 in 5th species counterpoint?

Tags: counterpoint

Since a mixture of note values is used in 5th species can someone please explain why this is not permissable in 5th species writing? Preparing a suspension on the 4th beat is very common in real music and I find that having to prepare the suspension only on beat 3 a bit boring and limiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brief answer: Palestrina wouldn't generally have written a suspension with that note value (i.e., a quarter note before a downbeat) in a sacred piece.  Species counterpoint often has rules that imitate that style.**

---

Details:

I'm not sure which book you may be getting your information from -- species "rules" are always a bit arbitrary and can vary from source to source and textbook to textbook.

However, the rationale is solid for this guideline.  That is, if the goal is to teach what species counterpoint was originally intended to do, i.e., imitate 16th-century style (like Palestrina).  Suspensions in 16th-century style were primarily a "white-note" device, at least in sacred style.  While modern time signatures weren't used yet, a lot of music was written in the equivalent of modern 4/2 (or 2/1) time.

Within that, suspensions in their most basic form consisted of semibreves that generally occurred on beat 2 or 4 of a 4/2 bar.  In modern terms, they looked like "whole notes," but because of barlines today, they'd generally be written with tied half notes.  The preparation would be a half note (minim) in length, the actual suspension would be a half note in length, and the resolution downward by step would also be a half note in length.

Suspensions in black notes, i.e., with shorter note values like a quarter note (semiminim) preparation, were rare in traditional sacred Palestrina-style, though they became more common as black note durations became common in the 1600s (for all genres).

That's not to say that black notes played no role in suspension figures.  There were a lot of stereotypical ways of ornamenting a suspension.  To use modern terminology, one might have an anticipation of the resolution in black notes, sometimes also with a turn involving a lower neighbor in eighth notes (fusae). Sometimes in black notes you'd see a leap down from the suspended note to a note consonant with the bass before returning up to the resolution note.  And although the stereotypical suspension in white notes had a half note resolution, you'll frequently see black notes dividing that resolution note and continuing in passing motion or something.

Overall, the template of the suspension was always in white notes, and the one note you couldn't generally mess with in terms of duration was the preparation, which was invariably a half note or longer.  (Actually, you couldn't mess with the duration of the suspension itself either, but there were certain stereotypical ornaments that were allowed as described above.)

If you look at fifth species examples given in Fux, for example, there are plenty of examples of suspensions with the types of ornaments I've mentioned (sometimes involving black notes), but the suspensions themselves always happen with a preparation and suspension duration that works in white notes (like 4th species does).

As to why this was part of 16th-century style, I don't know that there's any rationale except that the suspension originally developed in a primarily "white-note" world.  Also, in the notation of the time (which lacked barlines and ties), it was simply easier to notate and read a white-note suspension as a disruption at the usual pulse levels (which would have been felt at the half note or even whole note level in modern terms).  A syncopation that began on a quarter note "off beat" would be more disruptive to the rhythmic pulse and simply harder to read for singers at the time who would lack a score, not to mention ties and barlines to clarify where strong beats occur.  (Not that it doesn't happen -- it does.  But it's much more rare, again particularly in sacred style.  And species counterpoint is about teaching very common stylistic norms.)

The rules of what sort of dissonances could occur in longer vs. shorter note values were pretty regimented in the 16th century: certain types of dissonances only happened in black notes, and other types were primarily a white-note phenomenon (like suspensions).  It just had to do with the general rhythmic pace of various kinds of dissonances and ornaments in that style.

> Preparing a suspension on the 4th beat is very common in real music

Again, not in sacred style from the mid-1500s, which is where a lot of species rules come from.  Later composers who learned from species counterpoint in the 18th century understood this.  But they were being taught the "template" of what a proper suspension is, which not only involves a weak beat and strong beat with a tie, but also proper durations for preparation, suspension, and resolution.  If there are ornaments, there should be proper durations for all of those relative to the length of the overall suspension.  If you look at suspensions in, say, Bach, sure, you'll see a lot of them in black notes.  But, they were still generally follow the *pacing* of the Palestrina-like guidelines in terms of how long relatively the various stages of the suspension are.  If there are ornaments, they are appropriately scaled down in note values too.  Similarly, if Bach does write a longer suspension with a half note preparation, you'll see the pacing of the length of the suspension itself, the placement of the resolution, etc. scaled up.

Species counterpoint is about teaching beginning students the basics.  So restricting suspensions to one note value until they master all of the details about how suspensions work is not a bad idea.